# Clear previous printed line on online-python editor

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this is something that has been asked before, but I have tried most of what people have told me to do and none of it has worked.  The most agreed upon method of clearing the last printed screen is to use `\r`, but it hasn't really been working for me.

My code:

```
import time 
import sys

frames = ["[    ]", "[=   ]", "[==  ]", "[=== ]", "[ ===]", "[  ==]", "[   =]", "[    ]", "[   =]", "[  ==]", "[ ===]", "[====]", "[=== ]", "[==  ]", "[=   ]"]

while True:
    for frame in frames:
        print('\r' + frame, end='')
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

The output ends up printing every single new iteration as a new line.

```
[    ]
[   =]
[  ==]
[ ===]
[====]
[=== ]
[==  ]
[=   ]
[    ]
[=   ]
[==  ]
[=== ]
[ ===]
[  ==]
[   =]
[    ]
[   =]
[  ==]
[ ===]
[====]
[=== ]
[==  ]
[=   ]
[    ]
[=   ]
[==  ]
[=== ]
[ ===]
[  ==]
[   =]
[    ]
[   =]
[  ==]
```

I'm not sure what mistake I am making but if someone could please enlighten me that would be amazing.  Thank you.

(Some other information.  I am using [online-python.com](https://www.online-python.com/) to write this, and they are on version 3.8.5)

Comment: It looks like online-python.com treats carriage returns as newlines. If you try running the code locally, it should work, at least on a Unix-based terminal.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine for me and  i can not replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is a problem with the online IDE. I ran your code on a regular IDE (PyCharm Community) and it worked perfectly fine. I would consider using software installed on your PC. Pycharm is really beginner-friendly and I would fully recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Just made a game using

```
import os
```

at the top

then

```
os.system('Clear')
```

just above the next print statement. Don't know if that's what you are trying to do

Comment: Maybe a typo? Should be `clear` not `Clear` right?